# How can I filter by the text entered in the filter in PrimeNG?

Tags: angular, dropdown, primeng

I have an array strings that I display in a dropdown. I want to filter based on the value entered in the filter field of the dropdown. The issue is I don't know what needs to be entered to the filterBy attribute of the dropdown. I know in case of a class we can enter the properties of the class but what about a string? How can I filter based on the string value itself?

```
<p-dropdown [options]="example_array_of_strings" [(ngModel)]="selected_string" [filter]="true" filterBy=""</p-dropdown>
```

I tried tricking it by entering toString() to the filterBy attribute since strings have toString() function too by default, however it didn't work either. How can I specify to filter based on the value of the item instead of some specific property of it?

Comment: May `AutoComplete`  suite is case much better? https://primefaces.org/primeng/autocomplete

Comment: Also a great option, thank you, I might switch to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [PrimeNG Docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/dropdown) options shall be objects:

> An array of objects to display as the available options.

So i guess an easy solution would be to convert your string array into an array of objects for example like so:

```
selected_string: string;
options: any[];
example_array_of_strings: string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

stringToObject() {
    this.example_array_of_strings.foreach(example_string => {
        this.options.push({ label: example_string });
   });
}
```

If you call the key "label" the dropdown will automatically take "label" as its *optionLabel* and its *filterBy* (if you call it anything other than "label" you have to tell the dropdown what you called it) so you just have to set the *optionValue* to "label" as well if you want the selected item as a string not an object:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="options" [(ngModel)]="selected_string" optionValue="label" filter="true"></p-dropdown>
```

Actually there is a [pull request](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/pull/11398) to make filter work with a list of array as options, but i guess it hasn't been accepted. But you can keep an eye on that and maybe filtering a array of strings will work by default in the future.

Hope i could help you :) have a nice day

Max

Comment: Thank you so much, it's a pity that for now filterBy only works with objects but this is a great workaround, I really appreciate it. You too have a nice day :)